# Get Meta from Custom Field of Image URL

Tags: custom-field, images, page-template

I have a custom field that is an Image and the return value of the field is Image URL.

I have custom page templates where I render these image fields. Is there a way to get the meta info for the image through the image url. I do not want to change the return value to Image Object or Image ID.

Comment: What meta info do  you need from that URL ? ( exif data , size , dimensions )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed the code in functions.php so that I could re-use it. Here's my solution below:

```
function get_img_alt($attachment) {    
  $post = get_post();
  $image_id  = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $attachment, true );
  $image_alt = get_post_meta($image_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
  print $image_alt;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I can already tell that you're using ACF - if you don't want to change the return settings for the field, you can bypass ACF and just pull the image ID directly from post meta:

```
$image_url  = get_field( 'my_field_name' );
$image_id   = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_field_name', true );
$image_meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $image_id );
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll give this a try. Is there a way to do this globally for all images? I did something similar (but with Image Object). I created a function where I pass the field name, which is not that big of a deal. But is there a way to get this globally - adding alt tags automatically for all images.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "get this globally"? As in, do you want a helper function that you can easily use anywhere, or do you want to somehow "hook" into the ACF `get_field` call (although if the latter, I question why you don't want to change the return settings).

Comment: Your code doesn't work. I basically want a function I can call that will get me the alt tag f an image URL from ACF image field.

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't very helpful. I'm pretty sure it's correct, but if you elaborate we can solve it together.

Comment: @essjay sounds like a question for ACF's support channels

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Thanks for your help. Your code sent me in the right direction. The reason why it wasn't working was because I needed it in functions.php. I provided my answer below

Thanks again.